# visual studio 2019: remote debugger can not find remote computer

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to establish remote debugging from my work laptop to a remote server in my organization. I run VS 2019 and i installed remote debugging tools for VS 2019 in the remote computer. I also started the Remote Debugger in the target machine. When i try to attach to process from my laptop, Visual studio could not find the remote computer.

Note: My laptop and the remote machine are in different domains and i am not sure if this is a limitation because of which the remote computer is not visible.

Your help is much appreciated.